# Github action workflow schedule is not updating

Tags: github-actions

I have a project that's scheduled to run every 6 minutes and works (runs every ~12min). I changed the schedule to run every hour but it's still running at the old cadence (every ~12min).

Why is this? Do I need to disable and re-enable workflow in the settings to execute the change to the schedule?

workflow file: https://github.com/hanniabu/validator_queue_monitoring/blob/main/.github/workflows/update_validator_data.yml

old schedule:

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '*/6 * * * *'
```

new schedule:

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '* */1 * * *'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your new cron is correct.

You can use handy tool like [crontab](https://crontab.guru) to check if the cron is correct or not.

For your cron: `* */1 * * *` it basically runs each hour and for every minute (essentially every minute)

Also From the GitHub actions [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule):

> The shortest interval you can run scheduled workflows is once every 5
> minutes.

So you are essentially saying github actions to run your workflow every minute, hence it tries to run it every 5 minutes instead.

Adding in the workload on GitHub actions, it is running for every 12 minutes practically.

If you want to run your workflow every hour then use this cron: `0 * * * *`